# Add a static block to specific pages

Tags: static-block

I need to add static block which I created from back end to specific pages like user dashboard, login page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

use this where ever you want

call your .phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it si possible
there are two methods

using phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('id-of-cms-block')->toHtml();?>
```

or using xml

```
<block type="cms/block" name="layout-name" before="-">
  <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>id-of-cms-block</block_id></action></block>
```

regards

Comment: I need to add this block to top of the page. Like header

Comment: in this case you should use the xml version and add it int the <reference name="header"> session of you local.xml (please refer to the page.xml for further reference. Or you can take the short path and add the  createBlock... instruction in your header.phmtl file

Answer (score 0):

Just place this bit of code on the .phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your-block-id')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Replace your-block-id with the block id that you wand to use.